# Embedded Solr DIH

Tags: solrj, dih

Can anyone tell me how to configure Embedded Solr DIH in Solrj?
I tried this..

`SolrQuery qry = new SolrQuery();
    qry.setQueryType("/import");
    qry.setParam("command", "full-import");
    qry.setParam("clean", false);
    embeddedSolrServer.query(qry);`

And it stops at this point.

> 1437 [main] INFO org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer - registering core: main
>
> 1468 [Thread-1] INFO org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImporter - Starting Full
>   Import
>
> 1468 [main] INFO org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore - [main] webapp=null
>   path=/import params={qt=%2Fimport&command=full-import&clean=false}
>   status=0 QTime=15

After this I expect to get something like this as in Solr HTTP Server  :

> Read import.properties
>
> org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.JdbcDataSource$1 call  Creating a
>    connection for entity id with URL: jdbc:mysql://localhost/solrdb
>
> org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.JdbcDataSource$1 call

And so on...

Thanks in advance    :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
URL url = new URL(completeUrl);
HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
```

See how I did it [here](http://code.google.com/p/solr-data-import-scheduler/source/browse/trunk/org/apache/solr/handler/dataimport/scheduler/HttpPostScheduler.java#132).

Comment: We say thanks by accepting an answer (if it's your question) and/or upvoting it (meaning: I find this answer useful).

Comment: But my question is how to use EmbeddedSolrServer for Data Import. I can do with HttpSolrServer but not with Embedded one.