# 'SolrCoreState already closed' with unit test using EmbeddedSolrServer v 5.2.1

Tags: java, solr, integration-testing

Im trying to read 7-8 xml files of data that contain realistic data from our production server. Then I would like to read this data into EmbeddedSolrServer to test for edge cases for our custom date search. The use of EmbeddedSolrServer is purely to separate the data testing from any environment that might change over time.

I would also like to avoid writing plumbing-code to import each field from the xml since I already have a working DIH.

Seting up an integration test with EmbeddedSolrServer I get error:
*ERROR o.a.s.h.dataimport.DataImporter - Full Import failed:java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: SolrCoreState already closed*

The code for setting up the integration test is:

```
public class SolrEmbeddedSearchTest extends AbstractSolrTestCase {

static {
    System.setProperty("solr.allow.unsafe.resourceloading", "true");
    ClassLoader loader = SolrEmbeddedSearchTest.class.getClassLoader();
    loader.setPackageAssertionStatus("org.apache.solr", true);
    loader.setPackageAssertionStatus("org.apache.lucene", true);
}

private SolrClient server;
private final String SolrProjectPath = "\\src\\test\\resources\\solr-5.2.1\\server\\solr\\nmdc";
private final String userDir = System.getProperty("user.dir") +  SolrProjectPath;

@Override
public String getSolrHome() {
    return userDir;
}

@Before
@Override
public void setUp() throws Exception {
    super.setUp();

    initCore("solrconfig.xml", "schema.xml", userDir, "collection1");
    server = new EmbeddedSolrServer(h.getCoreContainer(), h.getCore().getName());

    SolrQuery qry = new SolrQuery();
    qry.setRequestHandler("/dataimport2");
    qry.setParam("command", "full-import");
    qry.setParam("clean", false);        
    server.query(qry);
}

@Test
public void testThatResultsAreReturned() throws Exception {

    SolrParams params = new SolrQuery("Entry_ID:imr_1423");
    QueryResponse response = server.query(params);
    assertEquals(1L, response.getResults().getNumFound());
    assertEquals("1", response.getResults().get(0).get("Entry_ID"));
}
}
```

And when run causes this stacktrace:

`DEBUG o.a.s.u.processor.LogUpdateProcessor - PRE_UPDATE add{,id=imr_1423} {qt=/dataimport2&expandMacros=false&config=dih-config.xml&command=full-import}
15:40:38.713 [Thread-2] WARN  o.a.s.handler.dataimport.SolrWriter - Error creating document : SolrInputDocument(fields: [Entry_Title=...])
org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: SolrCoreState already closed`

Here is the complete stacktrace: https://gist.github.com/emoen/f6c2f80b7ba09a59fa6b - exception starts at line 683.

Schema.xml, solrconfig.xml, and dih-config.xml has been copied from a standalone Solr 5.2.1 instance that works.

Why is SolrCoreState closed before setup has finished and the data imported with handler: /dataimport2 ?

What is the best way of doing dataimport with EmbeddedSolr? Ive tried the method suggested here: [Embedded Solr DIH](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11951695/embedded-solr-dih) but solr is closed before the http request is sent.

Debugging the code - it looks like this line
`initCore("solrconfig.xml", "schema.xml", userDir, "collection1");`
initializes the core twice.

In solrconfig.xml I define dataDir with
 `<dataDir>F:\prosjekt3\nmdc\source\central-api\src\test\resources\solr-5.2.1\server\solr\configsets\nmdc\data</dataDir>`

When reading solrconfig.xml the log picks this up:
`DEBUG org.apache.solr.core.Config - solrconfig.xml dataDir=F:\prosjekt3\nmdc\source\central-api\src\test\resources\solr-5.2.1\server\solr\nmdc\collection1\data`

But further down the log it is using another dataDir:

```
INFO  org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore - CORE DESCRIPTOR: {name=collection1, config=solrconfig.xml, transient=false, schema=schema.xml, loadOnStartup=true, instanceDir=collection1, collection=collection1, absoluteInstDir=F:\prosjekt3\nmdc\source\central-api\src\test\resources\solr-5.2.1\server\solr\nmdc\collection1\, dataDir=C:\Windows\Temp\no.nmdc.solr.request.SolrEmbeddedSearchTest_4D0704B125401CE0-001\init-core-data-001, shard=shard1}
```

And it starts loading the jar files, reading solrconfig.xml and schema.xml for the second time.